# RPMs increase to 3000 after shifting into neutral

Tags: manual-transmission, iac-valve

When I shift into neutral in my 2004 2.0L manual Ford Escape, the RPMs hover at where they were at when I was in gear, and then increase/hold at ~3000 RPMs for about 5 seconds before decreasing.

I replaced the IAC valve since this was the most common solution for this behavior I saw on threads, but the issue persisted.

I did notice after replacing the IAC valve that the issue doesn’t start until the car warms up. Everything works great when in gear.

I checked for codes but there weren’t any. I performed some tests with the code-reader and the only one that failed was the alternator text (voltage too low at 11.5). Would this be a cause? Or just another issue :D

Answer (score 0):

Some ecu's will limit engine rpm to 3k in it is not in gear and connected to the drivetrain.

Done to limit the engine hitting max rpm without load.

Answer (score 0):

This is a common symptom of an air leak in the crankcase ventilation system.  Check the rubber hoses for soft areas and splits.

If this is a zetec engine there is likely a hose running behind the inlet manifold that is prone to splitting and can cause this issue.